# Configure DEBUG log level for nimbus logs in apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

Is there way how we can enable debug for logs in apache storm. Not at the topology level but for Master node(nimbus.log). Wanted to enable DEBUG level for nimbus.log to understand how exactly scheduling works.
I have already gone through dynamic logging using UI for topologies.

Answer (score 0):

The non-worker logging is configured in the storm/log4j2/cluster.xml file https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/log4j2/cluster.xml#L86. This is a standard Log4j2 configuration file, so refer to the Log4j2 documentation for how this works.

You should be able to just add a new logger at the bottom there for the package(s) you want logs from, and set the level to DEBUG.